# IIllegalArgumentException while trying to resolve dependency in SBT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have an Scala project (SBT) in Intellij. I would like to include following dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "9.3.3.v20150827"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % "9.3.3.v20150827"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.3.3.v20150827"
```

Unfortunately, I get errors:

> unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-webapp;9.3.3.v20150827:
>   several problems occurred while resolving dependency:
>   org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-webapp;9.3.3.v20150827
>   {compile=[default(compile)]}: [error]     several problems occurred while
>   resolving dependency: org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-project;9.3.3.v20150827
>   {}: [error]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency:
>   org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-parent;25 {}: [error]
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
>   [error]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host =
>   null [error]  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host
>   = null [error]  [error]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null [error]     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null [error]  [error]
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
>   [error]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host =
>   null [error] Use 'last' for the full log.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be some network / repository setup issue. Works for me:

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "9.3.3.v20150827"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % "9.3.3.v20150827"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.3.3.v20150827"
```

sbt:

```
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-server-9.3.3.v20150827.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-server;9.3.3.v20150827!jetty-server.jar (5608ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-servlet-9.3.3.v20150827.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-servlet;9.3.3.v20150827!jetty-servlet.jar (3476ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-webapp-9.3.3.v20150827.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-webapp;9.3.3.v20150827!jetty-webapp.jar (2489ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-http-9.3.3.v20150827.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;9.3.3.v20150827!jetty-http.jar (2783ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-io-9.3.3.v20150827.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;9.3.3.v20150827!jetty-io.jar (3279ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;9.3.3.v20150827!jetty-util.jar (7722ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-security-9.3.3.v20150827.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-security;9.3.3.v20150827!jetty-security.jar (2490ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.3.3.v20150827/jetty-xml-9.3.3.v20150827.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-xml;9.3.3.v20150827!jetty-xml.jar (1945ms)
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 53 s, completed 3 Sep, 2015 11:17:11 PM
> sbtBinaryVersion
[info] 0.13
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_80).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
scala> util.Properties.version
versionMsg            versionNumberString   versionString         

scala> util.Properties.versionString
res3: String = version 2.10.5
```

Check your Java / Scala and repository settings.

Also try adding this resolver to your `build.sbt` or  `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

Comment: Could you send me URLs of repos you use?

Comment: I have no special repositories setup.

Comment: It was indeed problem with repos. My repositories file in .sbt was broken. Thank you for help.